# thread_local storage, constructors, destructors, and tbb

Tags: c++, tbb, thread-local-storage

It's my understanding that tbb may maintain pool threads for reuse... is there a way to ensure that data that I have declared using a modern C++ implementation as `thread_local` and with a non-trivial (default) constructor and destructor, which is initialized whenever the data is first used from a new thread is destroyed when tbb puts a thread into its pool and constructed again when the thread is pulled out of the pool? I am, as I said, currently just declaring my data as static and using the C++ `thread_local` specifier.

EDIT:

Apologies for not spelling this out initially, but an early respondent has made it clear that some assumptions might be made about the code I am hoping to update which are not valid.

1. Refactoring usage of tbb isn't practical, because the code makes heavy use of it already and it is non-trivial to refactor them all, but I will need the threads created by it to still have access to the thread local data.
2. A have hidden all access to thread_local data behind a small number of functions, which is what I was ideally hoping to change.  Is there some way, perhaps with an additional thread_local value, that I can tell that I'm on a thread that has been reused since the last time the data was accessed?   This is actually the ideal solution I would be looking for.
3. One major disadvantage I find with refactoring all tbb calls in the application is not so much that there are many of them (although that is certainly a significant factor), but that then I am adding references to thread_local data in every single tbb thread, even if that particular thread did not ever actually need to access it.  On systems which delay construction  of thread_local data until it is first accessed, this overhead is undesirable.  This is why, ideally, I would like to put the logic for it inside of the functions that accesses the thread_local data.

Comment: Easiest solution is probably to wrap your tasks in a function that uses RAII to initialize the `thread_local` when the task begins, and clear it when the RAII object is destroyed. Since the task itself monopolizes the thread (and therefore its thread locals) while running, you just need to have the lifetime of the task implicitly initialize and clear the thread local.

Comment: Regrettably, this idea would not be easy to do at this time. See updates to the question.  Thanks for the input, however.

Comment: I'd avoid using `thread_local` data *at all*. Can you put that data into some object(s) that live in the task?

Comment: What's the current structure of your project? Have you got a project heavily using tbb that you want to add a function with `thread_local` data to, or a project full of functions with `thread_local` data that you want to add tbb to, or a project with both that is currently incorrect?

Comment: The current structure of the project is a lot of tbb usage and a small set of functions that wrap thread_local data that was more recently added and is needed by some lower level functions in the application, many of which are indirectly accessed via tasks that may have been handed over to tbb for parallelization.  I am witnessing undesirable behavior in the program that I cannot easily explain, however, unless tbb is pooling the threads, and is not destroying what the last thread usage may have left behind and reinitializing it when it gets reused.

Comment: @markt1964 I believe you misuse `thread_local`. If this is the issue you are having then you should use something else. What you ask is rather contrary to the design of `thread_local` and has nothing to do with tbb in particular.

Comment: I have need some global data that is local only to a particular thread.That is my understanding of what thread local is for.  The problem I am finding is that it appears as that sometimes a thread gets reused by tbb, and the behavior I am observing is consistent with the notion that the thread_local data appears to be in a stale state from the last time the thread was used.  Needing to go and explicitly initialize the data every time I start a thread in tbb is theoretically possible, but tedious and liable to be error prone.

Comment: Also, it introduces the overhead of forcing this initialization as every thread starts, rather than postponing the initialization until the data is actually needed, because it is not necessarily required by every thread, but it isn't possible to distinguish which threads will need it from those that won't at the time that tbb is used to invoke the different tasks

Comment: Could you give a practical example of a function that wants to access such a `thread_local` variable and what the function intends to do with it? Because it really seems that you are misusing `thread_local`

Comment: @markt1964 the way you use it, is the same as global variables. And it is like first lesson in programming not to use global variables. Pretty much every multi-threading library reuses threads or has something like boost executors that can be run on multiple threads.

Comment: @markt1964 there are uses for global variables - singleton pattern - but it's purpose is to make a service rather than a variable.

Comment: For the general case, `thread_local` does precisely what I need: it provides an apparently global variable that is not touched by any other threads The problem I am witnessing however, is that when I use tbb to parallelize an operation, the thread_local data sometimes seems to have stale data in it, from the last time that thread was used. What I need is for some way tell in a function if tbb has recycled the current thread since the last time the function was called, and knows that this thread_local data actually needs to be reinitialized. I fully expect such a solution to be specific to tbb.

Comment: @markt1964 what you do is called global state. And threads are always recycled in almost any such library, except the rare cases at start up. Relying on a thread being constructed recently is ridiculous. It is a bad idea and can only be ensured by yourself if you create the threads yourself. And even then one can easily break it by accident. Say, even implementations of `std::async` can rely on a thread pool.

Comment: It's not so much that I expect the thread itself to be constructed recentlly as much as I need the thread_local data to be constructed recently, and be guaranteed to not reflect what any previous use of the thread might have done with it before it was returned to the pool for reuse.

Comment: @markt1964 What do you expect from a "normal" global variable when you use it on two different occasions? That it is somehow magically reinitialized to its initial state when you access it the second time? Why would it be different with a `thread_local` variable? Why not just make the variable local when you want it to be constructed every time a thread is resused?

Comment: @markt1964 If you can identify where you'd put a statement to "reinitialise" your global variable, you could instead have a statement that declares a local variable. Removing the globalness of your context data has other benefits, such as making testing the functions easier.

Comment: the thread local data in question is just default constructed when first used.   If it was ever explicitly initialized, I could just change the code there.  It appears I am not going to have much recourse but to explicitly reinitialize it on entry into each callback invoked via tbb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Program logic context and threads should be considered as another concept. Threads are used by your program context. Your program context might need one thread which is created and destroyed mutually with you program context, or might run on a thread provided from pooled thread, or might run on multiple threads which are created on demand or provide from thread pool.

- one thread

Your program context just have to use a thread local instance.

- pooled threads

Your program context needs to re-initialize/re-create a thread local instance, because the thread local instance was already used by a thread with another context and it is not irrelevant to your current program context.

- multiple thread

If your program context is composed of multiple threads(e.g. func a() run on thread t1, func b() run on tread t2), you should not to use thread local storage because the program context can not ensure data integrity.

In the code below, TBB assign a thread from pooled thread to a individual parallel_for context, so unless you initialize a thread local instance at first in your context, the data of this counting context would be collapsed.

```
#include <ranges>
#include <tbb/tbb.h>
using namespace std;
using namespace std::ranges::views;

int main() {
    class A{
    public:
        A(int ctx) : m_ctx(ctx){}
        int m_ctx;
        int m_num = 0;
    };
    thread_local A a(-1);  // already existing instance

    tbb::parallel_for(0, 7, 1, [](int i) {
        //a = A(i);     // re-initialize thread local
        a.m_ctx = i;    // not re-initize thread local, only assign context id 
        for (auto i : iota(0, 5)) {
            a.m_num++;
            printf("ctx=%d count=%d th=%d \n", a.m_ctx, a.m_num, tbb::this_task_arena::current_thread_index());
        }
     });
}
```

Output with not re-initializing a thread local instance. So, the count value is collapsed because that TBB assigns a thread which already used a thread local instance for another program context.

Output with no re-initialization is collapsed.

```
ctx=0 count=1 th=0
ctx=0 count=2 th=0
ctx=0 count=3 th=0
ctx=0 count=4 th=0
ctx=0 count=5 th=0
ctx=1 count=6 th=0
ctx=1 count=7 th=0
ctx=1 count=8 th=0
ctx=1 count=9 th=0
ctx=1 count=10 th=0
ctx=2 count=11 th=0
ctx=2 count=12 th=0
ctx=2 count=13 th=0
ctx=3 count=1 th=1
ctx=3 count=2 th=1
ctx=3 count=3 th=1
ctx=3 count=4 th=1
ctx=3 count=5 th=1
ctx=5 count=1 th=2
ctx=5 count=2 th=2
ctx=5 count=3 th=2
ctx=5 count=4 th=2
ctx=5 count=5 th=2
ctx=6 count=1 th=4
ctx=6 count=2 th=4
ctx=6 count=3 th=4
ctx=6 count=4 th=4
ctx=6 count=5 th=4
ctx=2 count=14 th=0
ctx=2 count=15 th=0
ctx=4 count=1 th=3
ctx=4 count=2 th=3
ctx=4 count=3 th=3
ctx=4 count=4 th=3
ctx=4 count=5 th=3
```

Output with re-initializing thread local instance. it works well.

```
ctx=0 count=1 th=0
ctx=0 count=2 th=0
ctx=0 count=3 th=0
ctx=0 count=4 th=0
ctx=0 count=5 th=0
ctx=1 count=1 th=0
ctx=1 count=2 th=0
ctx=1 count=3 th=0
ctx=1 count=4 th=0
ctx=1 count=5 th=0
ctx=2 count=1 th=0
ctx=2 count=2 th=0
ctx=2 count=3 th=0
ctx=2 count=4 th=0
ctx=2 count=5 th=0
ctx=5 count=1 th=2
ctx=5 count=2 th=2
ctx=5 count=3 th=2
ctx=5 count=4 th=2
ctx=5 count=5 th=2
ctx=6 count=1 th=0
ctx=6 count=2 th=0
ctx=6 count=3 th=0
ctx=6 count=4 th=0
ctx=6 count=5 th=0
ctx=4 count=1 th=3
ctx=4 count=2 th=3
ctx=4 count=3 th=3
ctx=4 count=4 th=3
ctx=4 count=5 th=3
ctx=3 count=1 th=1
ctx=3 count=2 th=1
ctx=3 count=3 th=1
ctx=3 count=4 th=1
ctx=3 count=5 th=1
```

Comment: Rather than assigning `a = A(i);`, you could declare `A a(i);`, local to the task

Comment: @Caleth It emulates questioner's situation for explanation. I think that questioner wants to re-initialize already existing thread local object, but he didn't provide any code, I don't know exact situations he is holding.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but you can use the following code to check if the thread has been recycled:

```
Code: Select all #include <tbb/tbb.h>

#include <iostream>
int main() {
tbb::task_scheduler_init init;
tbb::parallel_for(0, 10, 1, [](int i) {
std::cout << "Thread " << tbb::this_task_arena::current_thread_index() << " is running" << std::endl;
});

tbb::parallel_for(0, 10, 1, [](int i) {
std::cout << "Thread " << tbb::this_task_arena::current_thread_index() << " is running" << std::endl;
});
return 0;
}
```

```
Code: Select all Thread 0 is running
Thread 1 is running
Thread 2 is running
Thread 3 is running
Thread 4 is running
Thread 5 is running
Thread 6 is running
Thread 7 is running
Thread 8 is running
Thread 9 is running
```

Comment: I don't follow how that checks if the thread was recycled.